# Filter in NAV Source component , datetime

Tags: nav, kingswaysoft

I need to provide the "last 7 days" filter in NAV Source component, I have to use the XML encoded values.
I know that the date of today is "h", so how can I encode to write "last 7 days"?
I'd tried to write "(h-7) but it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to provide a value that is “7” days before the current date, you could easily do that in our **Premium Derived Column** component. And then write that to a variable using a function, and use that variable in Dynamics NAV Source component filter (using the “Insert Variables” feature available in the UI). The below expression in a Premium Derived Column component would help you to achieve this.

```
WriteValueToVariable(@[User::Date] , DateTimeToString(DateAdd( "dd", -7, GetDate()), "yyyy-MM-dd" ) )
```